# Multiple Conditions IF AND THEN statement SAS

Tags: database, if-statement, sas

```
data FINAL;
set FINAL;
if Visit="DC" and DIAGCANC ="N/A" then DIAGCANC="MISSING";
if Visit="MH" and MEDHIST ="N/A" then MEDHIST="MISSING";
if Visit="OLR" and OLRESP ="N/A" then OLRESP="MISSING";
if Visit="TLR" and TLRESP ="N/A" then TLRESP="MISSING";
run;
```

This is my code for an IF AND THEN statement. This format of code (If and then) has been used earlier in my code and has worked fine.
For some reason I can't understand, there is no change made in the output when i run this. There are also no errors.

Here is the output I get for a little more insight.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rux8.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you checking variable `visit`? The image indicates the variable labelled `ARM A` contains the visit values.  What is the output from `PROC CONTENTS DATA=FINAL VARNUM;`

Comment: My apologies. For some reason, the data is Labeled in the output as ARM A, but sas reads it as Visit. if I were to change that to ARM_A it wouldn't be recognized by sas.

Comment: The name not matching the label can mean there was a `Proc TRANSPOSE` (with rename=). The next troubleshoot is to ensure the values in the data set are what you expect.  Try doing a `Proc FREQ` of `visit diagcanc medhist olresp tlresp` before the `data FINAL` step.  Look for leading spaces or other unexpected characters.  If everything looks ok, do the same FREQ with the variables formatted $HEX20 -- this can reveal hidden characters if there are any.  Hex 20 is a space, the other characters should be >= Hex 20 and probably < Hex 80

Comment: Don't do this: `data FINAL;
set FINAL;` This makes it hard to determine where the bug is and you need to re-run from the start. So recreate the FINAL data set and then write this to a new data set and try and check it.

Comment: Usually, in a search and replace step, it is a good idea to remove all spaces with `compress` and then search or equate.

Comment: shouldn't the `=` be `==` ?

Comment: Not if you're using SAS. @p._phidot_

Comment: I see.. thanks for that.  /(-_-)